# box behind video and picture gallery link but responsive

Tags: css, background, responsive

How to add a background box and two pictures like pic

[image]

So a side by side 2 pictures but the first boxed picture is where i put the links to the video: part 1 - part 2 like that with a photo of the video above and then to the right another photo that has text saying view gallery. Then repeat this responsive for every video.

I would love to have pretty buttons but google page speed said it couldn't see them clearly so I just stayed with text.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code? This is help site, not "make me a website" site. Anyway, here is one way to do it:

```css
.container {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width:100px;
  min-height:65px;
  margin-right: 20%;
  content:'sadasdasd';
  
  background: url(http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  
}

.image2 {
  //position:absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width:100px;
  min-height:65px;
  margin-left: 0 20%;
  content:'sadasdasd';
  background: url(http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/galleries/travel/hubs/thebigpicture/the-big-picture-photography-competition-round-393/Fary-Afshar-xlarge.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it's not make me a website, i just couldn't find how to put a background behind two pictures as one block.  I could do it with one but not two.